# Is it possible create Megumin in D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

Recently I watched an anime called Konosuba and I loved the archmage style. She can only cast the Explosion spell and only once a day because it drains all her mana and after casting the spell she can’t move for  a while. Is it possible to create Megumin in this game if so how do I do it?

For context Megumin as a character knows only the Explosion spell (which is essentially just a massively explosive fireball) and refuses to learn any other form of magic. Casting that spell takes all of her energy or mana and leaves her completely unable to move for a while and even after, she is unable to cast it again for the remainder of the day (barring special circumstances in the anime).

Comment: João please explain your goal here. Are you looking to create a character who cannot move after casting a spell?  Are you familiar with [how spells work](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting) in D&D 5e?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, especially concerning how "Megumin" works and what she (?) can do? Right now, your question is pretty unstructured and short, and considering the overlap between people who know both 5e and Konosuba might be rather small, it would probably increase the chances of a (useful) answer significantly if you elaborated what the character is supposed to be able to do.

Comment: Another side note: by looking at your profile, it appears that most of your questions start out with similarly "improvable" phrasing until they are "edited into shape" by others. I can't tell if that's a result of you being not that well-versed in the English language (which is nothing to be blamed for) or if it's simply a lack of effort on your side. If the latter is true, I would ask you to change that, please - when asking others to invest a (potentially rather significant) amount of time into writing a good answer, putting more effort into a well-written question is the least one can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can't really do this in D&D 5e (but could in AD&D).

In D&D terms, Megumin is an arcane spellcaster who can only cast one exceptionally powerful spell per day, which consumes all of her power.

However, none of the core classes in D&D 5th edition can do this, exactly. The mechanics of arcane spellcasting use spell slots, so that it's not possible to spend all your MP on a single strike. The generally well-balanced nature of D&D 5e, and limit on the number of first-party splatbooks compared to earlier editions, limits the ability of player characters to channel all their offensive power into a single attack.

However, we can build something akin to Megumin.

#### Approximate equivalent to Megumin in D&D 5e

Sorcerers in D&D 5e gain sorcery points, and their Flexible Casting ability allows them to convert spell slots into sorcery points. You could, in theory, convert all your spell slots to sorcery points, given several rounds of preparation. This would meet two requirements of a Megumin build:

- Can only cast one spell per day
- Takes a long time in preparation to cast this spell

Metamagic allows the sorcerer to spend sorcery points to empower their spells. A level 6 character—canonically Megumin's character level at the beginning of the series, assuming equality with D&D's levels, which is not unreasonable since the goddess Aqua is level 21—could accumulate 22 sorcery points this way by spending 9 bonus actions, or one minute.

You can therefore apply both Empowered and Heightened Spell to a *fireball*, giving you a reroll on damage dice and giving one target disadvantage on the saving throw, for a total cost of 4 sorcery points.

- This meets the requirement of one very powerful fire spell per day.

However, you can only spend 4 sorcery points this way. This means that you have enough sorcery points and spell slots to cast these empowered heightened *fireball* three times per day, rather than Megumin's one per day. **The limit is that there's no way to channel all this power into a single spell per day**.

At sorcerer levels 7, 9, and 11-20, you will only have one spell per day of your highest level spell. However, you can't sacrifice all your low level spells to empower it, as the limit on spending sorcery points still applies.

That said, it's canonically the case that Megumin actively refuses to learn any spell except Explosion, so it's possible that she merely has one powerful spell of her highest level and simply refuses to learn any spells in her lower-level slots. In that sense, a valid representation of Megumin is merely one who casts a single empowered spell; though, again you can't actually sacrifice all your low-level slots to further empower it.

You also can't really have the character faint from exhaustion. There are exhaustion rules, but there are no official rules by which spellcasting would exhaust you.

#### However, you *could* do this in AD&D 2nd edition

A quick search reveals an article titled [D&D's influence on Konosuba](https://orbitalflower.github.io/tv/anime/dnd-influence-konosuba.html), which posits that in AD&D 2nd edition it was indeed possible to play a Megumin character using the custom character class rules in a certain sourcebook:

> AD&D 2nd edition expansion *Player’s Option: Spells & Magic* actually made it possible to construct a custom wizard class that only knows one specific type of magic, has trouble learning new spells, can only cast one extremely powerful spell per day, has to chant dramatically to cast it, and collapses at the end.
>
> The cover of that same book features a wizard attacking a castle with a massive fireball.

The spell points and custom character class creation rules in *Player’s Option: Spells & Magic* allow you to create an actual hyper-focused level 6 character who can functionally channel all their "MP" into a single, extremely powerful home-made signature spell once per day, but will faint thereafter.

Answer (score 15):

### Explosion is literally just Fireball.

- Create a spellcaster that can cast Fireball.
- Never cast spells other than a single Fireball per day using your highest spell slot.

  - This will be a self-made restriction as you will have more spell resources and cantrips if you can cast Fireball in the first place.
- Be RP sluggish after you cast it.

### Don't expect playing Megumin as-is in a game to fly with most groups.

One of the big things about Megumin in Konosuba is that she is a flawed adventurer, not just a flawed character. Aside from her once-a-day usefulness at casting a highly powerful spell, she is a burden to her party. Her stubbornness to learn any other spells and become a well-rounded caster in favor of casting a single ultimate Explosion once a day is a selfish decision that prevents adventuring parties from making good use of her. As a result, she does not find her place in many adventuring parties and has to SETTLE for Kazuma's party, which is full of other burdenous characters that lack better prospects to replace her with. Eventually, in the show, Megumin becomes friends with her party and secures a place on their adventuring roster. However, this is purely by the design of the plot of the show. It was written this way to keep these characters together.

### Players are not *written* to like playing D&D with you.

While you may expect the wacky antics of Konosuba to unfold as it did in the show, Megumin would (as she was in the show) be kicked out of most adventuring groups for those antics. **This may not be fun for everyone else in your group.**

### Make sure your party will be cool with it.

Comment: Most groups I played with would eye OP's unwillingness to be useful as unwilling to play and then kick them from the group.

Comment: I forget the video that showed me this and I'll add a comment later if I find it but Explosion is actually a little closer to [Delayed Blast Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/delayed-blast-fireball) in terms of cast time and damage

Comment: Alternatively you can use [Meteor Swarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meteor-swarm) and the video I found is here [KONOSUBA IN D&D 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rah6r0uUr0E)

Comment: I suppose at high levels it would be plausible to have a spellcaster that did nothing except Time Stop/Delayed Blast Fireball. Would it be more possible to accomplish getting to Fireball then Multiclassing (assuming that's available in the group)?

Answer (score -1):

When I played this character idea I played as wild magic sorcerer. Casting fireball at highest level with metamagic available. Working with the Dm we treated the wild magic: anytime I rolled the 1 the character would pass out and would roll on a table for how long. So we didn't do the one and done but something that was fun, and the rest of the group didn't hate.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.